# Program doesn't properly Write / Read file when executed

Tags: java

I have a program that is supposed to write stuff into a file and then display the same file at the end of the program. I have a smaller test program that does the same thing and it works, but the original doesn't work.

```
while( input != 5 )
    {    
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter Selection (1-5): ");
        input = in.nextInt();

        File myFile = new File ("password.txt");
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(myFile);

        if(input == 1 )
        {    
            System.out.print("Password Length (6 +): ");
            inputLength = in.nextInt();
            if(inputLength >= 6)
            {   
                for(int codeLength = 0; codeLength <= inputLength;)
                {
                    randNum = random.nextInt(123);
                        if(randNum >= 97 && randNum <= 122)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                        else if(randNum >= 48 && randNum <= 57)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }

                }

                outFile.println("   " + codeNum + "\t" + code);
                outFile.close();
            }    
            else
                System.out.println("The password is too short");
        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {    
            System.out.print("Password Length (6 +): ");
            inputLength = in.nextInt();
            if(inputLength >= 6)
            {   
                for(int codeLength = 0; codeLength <= inputLength;)
                {
                    randNum = random.nextInt(123);
                        if(randNum >= 65 && randNum <= 90)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                        else if(randNum >= 48 && randNum <= 57)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                }

                outFile.println("   " + codeNum + "\t" + code);
                outFile.close();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("The password is too short");
        }
        else if(input == 3 )
        {    
            System.out.print("Password Length (6 +): ");
            inputLength = in.nextInt();
            if(inputLength >= 6)
            {   
                for(int codeLength = 0; codeLength <= inputLength;)
                {
                    randNum = random.nextInt(123);
                        if(randNum >= 33 && randNum <= 47)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                        else if(randNum >= 48 && randNum <= 57)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                }

                outFile.println("   " + codeNum + "\t" + code);
                outFile.close();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("The password is too short");
        }
        else if(input == 4 )
        {    
            System.out.print("Password Length (6 +): ");
            inputLength = in.nextInt();
            if(inputLength >= 6)
            {   
                for(int codeLength = 0; codeLength <= inputLength;)
                {
                    randNum = random.nextInt(123);
                        if(randNum >= 33 && randNum <= 126)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                        else if(randNum >= 48 && randNum <= 57)
                        {    
                            code+=(char)randNum;
                            codeLength++;
                        }
                }

                outFile.println(code);
                outFile.close();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("The password is too short");
        }
        else if(input == 5 )
        {
            System.out.print("Thank you for using Fast Pass :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again.");
    }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Here are your randomly generated codes:");

    System.out.println(code);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner("password.txt");
    while( inFile.hasNext() )
    {
        String file = inFile.next();
        System.out.println(file);
    }
```

What is supposed to happen is a display of the codes like
  1   --------
  2   --------

But what happens is the codes don't write into the file and then the file doesn't print when run

Comment: Everything aside, you have a lot of repeated code, a ton of it. So, do this: select all the code in any of the `if`-blocks where you are checking for `input`'s value to be....say 1 or 2, then right click and go to refactor -> then go to extract and then select method (or if you don't know how to) then simply Google "how to refactor and extract method in <whatever IDE that you are using>". Your code will be a lot better. 
Also, use a switch statement when you know exactly what the values that you need to check against so in this case instead of `input == 1`, use switch-case

Comment: I would recommend stepping through this with your debugger, to see what path you're actually taking through the code.  If you haven't run `outFile.close()`, you're not going to be able to open the file and read the data.

Answer (score -1):

In your `PrintWriter` constructor, pass in `true` as the second argument after wrapping the `File` argument using a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) (use the parameterized constructor with the `File` argument and `true` as the second argument for the `FileOutputStream`)
The `true` argument in the `PrintWriter` constructor is for enabling  auto flush and it works when you use methods like `println`, `printf`, or `format` (but not `write`, in that case you have to manually call the `flush` method)
[Here is the documentation for that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean))

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the reason for doing so? A constructive and logical argument is much appreciated over clicking and ghosting. Thank You.

Comment: I tried using flush but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @gabrielas6 you are going with `PrintWriter` so simply do something like `new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(myfile,true), true);` and see what happens. And in this approach you won't need to call `flush()`. See the docs I answered in the links.